# Creating directories in Google Buckets

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am writing a code which creates some files at a Google Bucket (that is in Google Cloud Storage).

To create a directory, one creates an empty file ending with slash, as the following Perl code does:

```
 my $EscapedName = uri_escape($DirName . '/');
 my $response = $ua->post("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/$Bucket/o?uploadType=media&name=$EscapedName",
                          'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
                          Content => "");
```

My question: I am going to store some (actually about a thousand) files (such as `d/x`, `d/y`, `d/z`) in a bucket. Should I create the directory `d/` before storing these files?

What are arguments both pro and counter creating the directory in Google Cloud Storage before populating it with files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCS does not have any built-in concept of a "directory." I could create the file "a/b/c/d/e/f" without there being a file named "a/" or a file named "a/b/". Heck, I could create an object named "a/////////////b", and that's a completely valid object name.

That said, there are several tools that, for convenience, pretend that directories exist. The command-line tool `gsutil` understands that an empty file ending in "/" represents a folder. Similarly, the cloud console also recognizes this format. However, neither tool requires it. If you create an object named "a/b/c/d", they will both pretend that folders "a", "a/b", and "a/b/c" exist, regardless of whether such placeholder directory objects exist.

Therefore there's no need to create such directory objects at all unless your application needs to use them for some reason. If it needs such placeholders to exist for some reason, then use them. For instance, if your application is modeling a file system and the existence of an empty directory has some inherent meaning, then you'll likely need some sort of "this is an empty directory" marker file.

If, however, you don't need them to exist, don't create them.